# Passing array values to javascript function and storing it in an variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays, function

Hello People please find my code below  as you can see iam trying to pass php array values to js function if i run this scipt i get 3 alerts parameter0=1,parameter1=2 and parameter2=3 differently...what iam trying to do is i need to save  parameter0,parameter1 and parameter3 so that i can pass it one more function....please help me to do this.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mufunc(a)
{
    var temp = new Array();
    dump(temp);
    temp = a.split('~');
    var parameter;
    for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
    {
        alert('parameter'+i+'='+temp[i]);               
    }
    //alert('sri'+i+'='+temp[i]);
}
</script>

<?php
$a = array('1','2','3');
$b = implode("~",$a);
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="mufunc('<?php echo $b; ?>')">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Why implode with a wacky delimiter? just do this `<?php echo implode(',',$b);`, and in your JS function: `var parameters= Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[0]);`, and paramters will be an array, that looks like this: `[1,2,3]`. Job done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `temp` in the global scope, so that it can be used later in any scope:

```
var temp = new Array();

function mufunc(a)
{
    dump(temp);
    temp = a.split('~');
    var parameter;
    for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
    {
        alert('parameter'+i+'='+temp[i]);               
    }
    //alert('sri'+i+'='+temp[i]);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
var params = new Array();

function mufunc(a)
{
    var temp= new Array();
    dump(temp);
    temp = a.split('~');
    var parameter;
    for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
    {
        alert('parameter'+i+'='+temp[i]);   
        params['parameter'+i] = temp[i];          
    }
}
```

Now you can access it like:

```
alert( params['parameter0'] );
alert( params['parameter1'] );
```

Comment: thanks for your reply serverbloke but its not working ...var temp = new Array();

function mufunc(a)
{
    dump(temp);
    temp = a.split('~');
    var parameter;
    for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
    {
        alert('parameter'+i+'='+temp[i]);               
    }
    alert(parameter0);
}

Answer (score 1):

do [this](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

```
$b = json_encode($a);
```

and look for JSON on stackoverflow or Google for how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Its working as your code is writen.

Your counts are different, one starts at 0, one starts at 1:

Try changing your start variable in the for loop to 1 and then minus 1 off the i in temp, you should get:

parameter1=1,parameter2=2 and parameter3=3

Answer (score 0):

Just use a global array variable, and assign parameters to that.

```
var parameter = [];
function mufunc(a)
{
var temp = new Array();
dump(temp);
temp = a.split('~');    
for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
{
    alert('parameter'+i+'='+temp[i]); 
    parameter[i] = temp[i];              
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of PHP's [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function on this one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function mufunc(a)
{
    // removed "var" to make "temp" global.
    // and we don't have to parse anything, the JS engine did
    // it for us already!
    temp = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
        alert(i + ": " temp[i]); 
    }
}
</script>

<?php
$a = array('1','2','3');
$object_string = json_ecode($a);
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="mufunc(<?php print $object_string; ?>)">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment could be considered an answer, I'll (re) post it here:

In your php script, just pass the arguments like so:

```
onclick="<?php echo implode(',',$b);?>">
//or if the you're dealing with strings:
onclick="<?php echo '"'.implode('","',$b).'"';?>">
```

And then do this in `myfunc`

```
function myfunc()
{
    var parameters = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[0]);
}
```

Arguments are available in all functions, and contain all data that was passed to that function as an argument, weather the function was defined with a certain number of arguments or not. [Read all about it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

The `arguments` object *looks* like an array, but isn't one, that's why -to slice it- you need to `apply` the slice method from the `Array` prototype. [MDN - Apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more info.

All in all, that's the quickest way to get to what you need, IMHO
*BTW: Don't use the array constructor, use the array literal notation: `[]`. The array constructor might behave a little odd from time to time*